# socialengine admin section some menus not working

Tags: socialengine

Please help me ...
I have installed socialengine(purchased) php in my localhost, when I am clicking on some menus they are not working like general setting is not working,

Can anyone suggest me how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You mush have login from admin member level account. Please try with superadmin or change your member level to "superadmin".

In socialengine, some menus will not work with moderator or admin member level.